# Loop through a group of indexes in groovy until value is found

Tags: loops, search, groovy

I have a web service response that provides me a block of data (in a long string), which I split into separate elements using the hard return as the separator. This gives me several sentences or elements (indexes I think), and each one has several data values within each element. For example:

```
//Gets data from web service response<br>
Def longstring =
"0   * 549 F7 G8 H9
1    2247 F6 G4 H10
17JUN DFWPHX F7
          M7 B2 Y1"

//Splits the above into separate sentences/elements
longstring.split("\\r?\\n")
String[] Element=longstring.split("\\r?\\n")

//Print out of elements<br>
Log.info Element[1] = "0   * 549 F7 G8 H9"
Log.info Element[2] = "1    2247 F6 G4 H10"
Log.info Element [3] = "17JUN DFWPHX F7"
Log.info Element[4]= "          M7 B2 Y1"
```

I have written a block of groovy code, which when provided the element ID, the code will try and drill down to get only a certain value within that element. For example, If Element[1], starts with "0" then do "x" thing, else do "y" thing. I need to be able to loop through all the elements (or indexes) with this same code until I come away with the information I need, then exit the iteration/loop once that data has been found.

I am not a groovy expert. I've seen the google results for maps, loops, and different operators. None of them make sense with my scenario. The text in each element is not a list. Mapping and looping seem to require a different set up than what I have. If you can help me solve this, please explain the code in simple terms if possible. Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: Could you paste actual code that compiles and demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Even after the formatting edit, that's not valid code

Comment: I'm sorry Tim, I know it's not valid code. I was trying to "paraphrase" the issue. It looks like I made things confusing by doing so. I'm using soapUI and creating a groovy script that pulls out a specific piece of data from a previous step within SoapUI. The groovy code is not my issue. The code works fine. I need help in understanding how to use that code to loop through several elements. Right now, my code is set up to evaluate only one element (i.e. Element[1]). As such it takes that line and does something with it. I'd like to be able to loop through all my elements with the same code.

Comment: If it helps, I can certainly post the code (it's very long and specific to my job). It may contain information that I'm not allowed to post in public. I'd have to clean it up so that it was more generic, which I can do if it helps you understand the issue better. Just let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @tim_yates, I tried posting the code and it's too long by 660 characters. Do I just split it up? New at this, so let me know the best way to get it to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me. I labeled it based upon how I was told it was designed

```
    //String that needs to be split
    def longString ="""0   * 549 F7 G8 H9
    1    2247  F6 G4 H10
    17JUN DFWPHX F7
           M7 B2 Y1"""


        //Splits the entire string response above into substrings based upon hard returns ("S" becomes the new chopped up strings)
    longString.split("\\r?\\n")
    String[] S=longString.split("\\r?\\n")

        //Creates the variable foundData for the loop to use below
    String foundData;


        //Creates "subS" variable for all the elements seen in the array "S" from above                                            
    for(String subS: S)                                                         
    {                   
                         //Creates a matcher pattern to look in each subelement (subS) where it looks for a regex pattern.
                         //Description of the regex used: /\d\s+(\d+).*/ = one digit followed by one or more spaces, followed by another one or more digits
                         //Note that the regex above includes: (\d+). This creates a "group" within the pattern, which is referred to below in the DataMatcher 
        def DataMatcher = (subS =~ /\d\s+(\d+).*/);                                                                                           

            //If the subelement (subS) matches the above pattern, it goes into the below block of code
        if (DataMatcher.matches())                                                
            {           //Sets the variable foundData (see above) to value of the DataMatcher and only grabs the data needed
                        //Note that the flightMatcher has two sections [0] and [1]. These represent the following:
                       //[0] = The entire string should be looked at
                       //[1] = Only group 1 in that string should be retrieved *See group created (in comments)  in the regex portion above
                  foundData = DataMatcher[0][1]; 
                       //This breaks the loop once the Data needed has been matched                                                 
                                break;                                                                                                                                                              
            }                             
    }

    //Displays the foundData needed
    log.info foundData
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand your need here, but I will give it a try. 
Assuming you want some piece of code to be executed based on the pattern of a line. I have an example here for you that tries do achieve this:

```
//Here I define 2 action closures - what I want to happen
def whenZero = { line ->
  println "The line '$line' starts with a zero"
}
def whenOne = {line ->
  println "The line '$line' starts with a one"
}

//Then I declare patterns and map them to each of the actions
Map methodMap = ['0.*':whenZero, '1.*':whenOne]

//This method will do the matching of the pattern and call any action
def executeBasedOnKey(Map map, String line){
  map.each{ key, method -> 
    if (line.matches(key)) method(line)
  }
}

//Your input
def longstring ="""0   * 549 F7 G8 H9
1    2247 F6 G4 H10
17JUN DFWPHX F7
          M7 B2 Y1"""

//This line calls the evaluation for each of the lines
longstring.split("\\r?\\n").each{line->
  executeBasedOnKey(methodMap, line)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joachim! I tried uploading the solution that worked for me, but the formatting is off. I can't get it to look like what you posted above. Not sure how to fix it so you can see it.